# NLP using NLTK take join between Tokenized list and csv file

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

```
mast_dict = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/ZAM/Desktop/LoughranMcDonald_MasterDictionary_2018.csv')
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
#print(stopwords.words('english'))

filtered_text = []
with open('C:/Users/ZAM/Downloads/HEURO/file0.txt') as fin:
    tokens = word_tokenize(fin.read()) 
for r in words:  
    if not r in stop_words:  
        filtered_text.append(r)
filtered_text = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in filtered_text]
filtered_text = [x for x in filtered_text if not (x.isdigit())]
print(filtered_text)
```

```
Output
['BEGIN', 'PRIVACYENHANCED', 'MESSAGE', 'ProcType', '2001MICCLEAR', 'OriginatorName', 'webmasterwwwsecgov', 'OriginatorKeyAsymmetric', 'MFgwCgYEVQgBAQICAf8DSgAwRwJAW2sNKK9AVtBzYZmr6aGjlWyK3XmZv3dTINen', 'TWSM7vrzLADbmYQaionwg5sDW3P6oaM5D3tdezXMm7z1TBtwIDAQAB', 'MICInfo', 'RSAMD5RSA', 'RHiO0hkbOslk2iB2eQM8lSgcXyjFKRha0FtFBz3xsf7Z6kKaWhrhStjKFZUvWZf', 'eDg67b8ZljTBWxC8ybQfg', ...]
```

The `mast_dict` variable contains around 86K English words with positive scores, negative scores, polarity scores, etc.
I want to make a joint between the `filtered_text`list which contains tokenized words as shown in the `mast_dict` CSV file so I can get the scores of the tokenized words in the `filtered_text` list.

Let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). It will make this much easier.

Comment: Any particular function of pandas you are aware of? @forgetso

Comment: It looks like you're not actually using `mast_dict` at all. What is in `words`? Are these the words from mast_dict? Can we have an example of what is in `file0`?